# automysqlbackup failes with ERROR 1045 (18000) Access denied ... after password change

Tags: mysql, backup, database, percona

I have two almost identical ubuntu database servers, and automysqlbackup  was happily running on both of them on using Percona 5.7 databases.

On one of them I have changed the database root password. Sucessfully apparently, as I can logon to the database via `mysql -u root -p` using the new password.

I updated the `/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf` file to include the new root password.

BUT, then automysqlbackup always failed with the dreaded error 1045 for user 'root'@'localhost'.

Rebooting the server made no difference.

When I change the database root password back to what it was, then everything works OK; even though the `/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf` file still has the 'changed/new' password!

So this one has me stumped. Does automysqlbackup cache the content of `/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf` somewhere that I need to purge?

Comment: why not dump it manually for the same way? test by change the user if it will really be read by nthe file

Answer (score 0):

tracked this one down. The issue is that automysqlbackup is taking the password from `/root/.my.cnf` rather than from `/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf`, even though the conf file is being used for some parameters.

Not clear why this is, but I am using [this](https://github.com/sixhop/AutoMySQLBackup/blob/master/automysqlbackup.conf) fork of automysqlbackup for 5.7 support which might have something to do with it.

So essentially, if you change the database password, then update the .my.cnf file, and the conf file too to make everything future proof.